# Qt+Mac: serial port doesn't answer on commands

Tags: macos, qt, serial-port, qextserialport

I use modified QExtSerialPort because I don't need any libs. I write to port successfully and successfully read from port if data  generated by device itself. But on my commands  to it it doesn't answer. bytesAvailable () always returns 0 on any attempt to read after successful  command record.
Under Windows all works fine.
I test com port with CoolTerm application and it work properly too.

How to fix this behavior?

Thx.